# Haskell filter using fst and snd in query

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to haskell and am trying to filter all the tuples where the first element is bigger than the second. I don't understand why this doesn't work, any help?

```
main = 
 do
  let xs = [2, 3, 2]
  let ys = [1, 2, 3]
  let cs = zip xs ys
  filter ((>snd).fst) cs
```

Comment: "first element is bigger than the second" — you're missing a comparison function [`(>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60-).

Comment: Please don't use a `do` block. A list is an instance of `Monad`, but `main` has type `IO a`, so another monad.

Comment: @andrybak I've changed the code and still getting an error, see the edit.

Comment: @LewisClark: this will not work, since `.fst` will extract the first element of the tuple, and then you aim to compare it with the *function* `snd`. But functions are not an instance of `Ord`, nor is a number `2` a function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if i don't use a do block it won't allow me to use "let"

Comment: @LEwisClarck: it does. In that case it is `let ... in`, so `let xs = [2,3,2] in let ys = [1,2,3] in zip xs ys`. This is *outside* a `do` block.

Comment: @LewisClark you can use explicit delimiters and write `let { xs = [2, 3, 2] ; ys = [1, 2, 3] } in ....expression....`.

Comment: @WillNess It just says "unexpected keyword "let"" in the compiler

Comment: post proper question with full code and error message please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
filter (\x -> fst x > snd x) cs
```

but you do not need to use `fst` or `snd` in the first place, you can work with [**`uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry):

```
filter (uncurry (>)) cs
```

`uncurry` takes a function `a -> b -> c`, and rewrites it to a function that takes a 2-tuple `(a, b)`, and thus calls the function with the elements wrapped in the 2-tuple.

Comment: Side note: `uncurry` is specialised to 2-tuples here; a more flexible way to write this while keeping it pointfree is to use the Applicative instance for functions: `(>) <$> fst <*> snd`; then if the pair is replaced with a proper data type, it could be changed to `(>) <$> someField <*> anotherField`, whereas to keep `uncurry`, you’d need to map the type into a pair first, with e.g. `uncurry (>) . (someField &&& anotherField)`.